# Commerce order rule save order

Tags: rules, commerce

I have a field in my orders which should be updated when an order is saved. I created a rule with the event "commerce order save", do the calculation for the field and at least save the order. But that logically gives me an endless loop.

How can I save the order without firing the event again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the '**Before saving a commerce order**' trigger in Rules.  It's right there in the 'Commerce Order' section.  Then you don't need a save action since it's about to be saved already...

That should do it for you!

Comment: That doesn't help, the endless loop will be triggered anyway because all the triggers listen to commerce_order_save(). So I need a way to bypass these triggers. Maybe I need to do manually db queries.

Comment: But why do you have commerce_order_save() in your rule?  Can't you do away with that if you use the event 'Before saving a commerce order'?

Comment: Okay thank you! That worked, I forgot that I haven't to save the order manually when using 'before saving'.